# Alternative to next method in JDBC Resultset

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Is there a way in JDBC that I extract more than a single row at a time ? The next method (of `ResultSet` class) allows one row at a time processing.

My query returns thousands of rows (just a single column for each row). The rows are very lean and I pretty much just want to extract the column values out. Looping through next, one row at a time is very slow for this use case.

Comment: Slow from developer productivity perspective or it's just *slow* at runtime? Also maybe you can aggregate these numbers somehow in the database (SUM, AVG...).

Comment: slow at runtime. It is not aggregation function that I need to run. Think of something like (select key from table where col1=val1.) Expected result is say 100,000 keys.

Answer (score 1):

While ResultSet only returns one row at time the jdbc driver should fetch amount of rows you have specified with Statement.setFetchSize()

> void  setFetchSize(int rows)
>
> Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be fetched from the database when more rows are needed for ResultSet objects genrated by this Statement.

I would also recommend setting the fetch direction properly when creating the Statement/PreparedStatement.